# Will adding X-Robots-Tag:noindex remove an already indexed page from searchresults

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I have a site that has already been indexed by google and shows in the search results. 
After it had already been indexed I added the X-Robots-Tag:noindex header to all responses. 
Is that enough for it to be removed from the search results the next time google tries to index it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But it will take time for the search engine to re-crawl the page and then remove the page from its index. But that header will effectively stop that page from being indexed. (unlike robots.txt which only prevents it from being crawled).